# Pytorch classifier output dimension

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, tensor, projection

I am trying to pass a tensor of size(1,12,512,512) into pytroch classifier, the layers of the classifier do not really matter. The output should be of the size(2) something as follow [0.5124,0.7557]. The classifier is not projecting the size of the tensor, although I did add some projection layers. I was wondering what is the best way to project the tensor of the size(1,12,512,512) into size(2) and pass that through the classifier. really appreciate the help.

This is what I tried, but did not work:

```
class cls(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, hid_dim, out_dim, dropout):
        super(SimpleClassifier, self).__init__()
        layers = [
            weight_norm(nn.Linear(in_dim, hid_dim), dim=None),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(dropout, inplace=True),
            weight_norm(nn.Linear(hid_dim, out_dim), dim=None)
            nn.Sigmoid()
        ]
        self.main = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.main(x)
        return logits
```

in_dim=512,
 hid_dim=512,
 out_dim=2
I thought I would add some more linear projection but did not work, I get an error about matrix multiplication being invalid because of some size issue. Not sure what I should do.

The expected behavior is the following for example:
tensor of size(1,12,512,512) ---> output:tensor([0.5124,0.7557])

Comment: You need to provide some code, to see what you did and how we can add or modify your code?

Comment: If the classifier output's size is 2. The output should be 2 values without any projection.

Comment: @Phoenix I did add the code that I tried, but it is not working. The output of that classifier shown in the code is a tensor of size(1,12,512,2).

Comment: Is (1,12,512,512)  the size of your input tensor? but look at the first layer in your model , its size not compatible with the input size!

Comment: I think you mean (512,512) is the input size and 12 is the batch size?

Comment: It is linear projection to bring the size of the tensor down. It worked on my side.

Comment: But you did not answer me. What is the size of your input? (512,512)?

Comment: Input size (1,12,512,512)

Comment: So, for example, your image will be (1,12,512,512), right? if so, your first linear layer should be with the same size .

Comment: Yes. It is just a tensor not necessarily an image.

Comment: But look at your first layer, it expects to receive 2D input : nn.Linear(in_dim, hid_dim)

Comment: How the tensor will be fed to the first layer, and they are not compatible!

Comment: That is not how linear projection works. Linear projection transform the a dimension in the tensor to hid_dim.

Comment: Could you please add an input to your question? (example)

Answer (score 0):

I write here, an example to understand my solution:

```
from torch.nn.utils import weight_norm 

class cls(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_dim,hid_dim,out_dim, dropout):
        super(cls, self).__init__()

        layers = [
            weight_norm(nn.Linear(in_dim, hid_dim)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(dropout, inplace=True),
            weight_norm(nn.Linear(hid_dim, out_dim)),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        ]
        self.main = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.main(x)
        return logits


x = torch.rand(512)  # <-- the first layer input size is 512.

model = cls(512,512,2,0.2)  # input=512, hidden=512, output=2 as in your question.

model(x)
```

> ```
> #output
>
> tensor([0.5249, 0.5026], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
> ```

**Second case:**

```
x = torch.rand(512, 512)   # No. batches = (512), input size = 512

#output                        the size is (512,2)
tensor(  [[0.4779, 0.4676],
          [0.4630, 0.5059],
          [0.4675, 0.5203],
          ...,
          [0.4641, 0.5179],
          [0.4877, 0.4733],
          [0.4103, 0.4845],
             ...
          [0.4442, 0.4981],
          [0.4616, 0.4990],
          [0.4673, 0.5278]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

**Third case:**

```
x = torch.rand(12, 512, 512)  # No. batches = (12, 512), input size = 512

#output                        the size is (12, 512,2) 
tensor([[[0.4779, 0.4676],
          [0.4630, 0.5059],
          [0.4675, 0.5203],
          ...,
          [0.4641, 0.5179],
          [0.4877, 0.4733],
          [0.4103, 0.4845]],
             ...
          [0.4442, 0.4981],
          [0.4616, 0.4990],
          [0.4673, 0.5278]]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

**Fourth case:**

```
x = torch.rand(1, 12, 512, 512)  # No. batches = (1, 12, 512), input size = 512

#output                        the size is (1,12, 512,2) 
tensor([[[[0.4779, 0.4676],
          [0.4630, 0.5059],
          [0.4675, 0.5203],
          ...,
          [0.4641, 0.5179],
          [0.4877, 0.4733],
          [0.4103, 0.4845]],
             ...
          [0.4442, 0.4981],
          [0.4616, 0.4990],
          [0.4673, 0.5278]]]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

In conclusion, your input `x` should be the same size as the input dimension of the first layer `nn.Linear` in your model. If your input size is larger than the input layer's size, PyTorch will process the additional dimensions with your input `x` as batches.